# How can I say "Life is full of uncertainty." in Russian?

Tags: перевод

How can I say "Life is full of uncertainty." in Russian?

Comment: "Жизнь как коробка шоколадных конфет: никогда не знаешь, какая начинка тебе попадется" :D

Comment: To me, this seems a legitimate question.   
No need to put it on hold, IMHO.

Comment: «Жизнь как коробка шоколадных конфет: никогда не знаешь, какая начинка тебе попадётся» - Forrest Gump

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation would be:

> Жизнь полна неопределенности.

But these sound more natural to me:

> Жизнь непредсказуема.
>
> Жизнь бывает непредсказуемой.

Comment: Спасибо  Ainar-G - мне нравится "Жизнь непредсказуема".

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Ainar-G's anwswer, you could also say :

"Жизнь полна неожиданностей." - Life is full of surprises.

or a bit more colloquial:

"Жизнь - непредсказуемая штука."  - Life is a unpredictable thing.

or you can be more poetic, and quote the epigraph from *Woe from Wit* :

> "Судьба - проказница шалунья, Определила так сама..."

Comment: vladlen  - Woe from Wit  А. С. ГРИБОЕДОВ; комедийная игра в кириллице - как русский, вы знаете пьесу по ее английскому названию, а не русскому?

Comment: да нет, пришлось лезть в википедию за английским названием )